# Can't use eyedropper in `<input type="color">` within Chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension, and have placed an `<input type="color">` element inside its popup window. It works OK, but the eyedropper tool (on Mac — see screenshot) does not respond or present the loupe when clicked.

[image: input color picker]

I thought it could be something to do with the extension's permissions, so tried a few different ones, including:

```
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabCapture",
    "desktopCapture",
    "pageCapture",
    "experimental",
    "system.display"
```

This is a private / internal extension, so permissions don't matter to me, but none of those (above) seem to work.

I'm not quite sure if this is a bug, an undocumented restriction, or a permission that I haven't yet found...

Comment: Check the console. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately nothing comes up at all in either the pop up or the active tab’s console... Also checked through the shadow-DOM element of the color picker in the inspector.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome then.